# input click event not working on IOS device with ionic 2 and angular2

Tags: ios, angular, input, click, ionic2

I try to upload image with a  in ionic 2 project . I need to customer the style and it's work with browser ,android. but it's not working on ios device.

I have try to set the style :cursor :point. but it's not woking too.

 html:

```
 <div class="upload-box J_UploadBox"  (click)="fileSelect.click()">
    <input class="J_UploadData" type="hidden" value="">
    <div class="box-do"><ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
      <span class="must-tip" style="display:none"></span></div>
    <div class="J_Views"><span class="tip">upload image</span></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="J_UploadInput" >
    <input type="file"   #fileSelect  (change)="onChange($event)"  accept="image/*">
  </div>
```

CSS:

[image]

is there anyone know why ?  thanks

Comment: Maybe there's an error happening inside `fileSelect.click()`... can you add this function to your question?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar dilemma which I resolved it by placing the `<input>` inside of a `<div>` formatted like an Ionic button like so:

**profile.page.html**

```
<div ion-button class="fileUpload">
  <span>Choose Picture</span>
  <input #fileInput class="upload" type="file" (change)="fileChangeListener($event)" />
</div>
```

**profile.page.scss**

```
.fileUpload {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

  input.upload {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  }
}
```